# What is the server URL for Notepad++'s Plugin Manager?

Tags: proxy, notepad++

I'm not able to use Notepad++'s update or plugin manager. I suspected it was a proxy problem, so I added my proxy to the plugin-manager settings but it still doesn't work.

Then I contacted my network admin and he said that he needs the server's URL to add it in the exception list. How can I find to what server it's trying to connect to?

**What IP/URL does Notepad++'s plugin manager connect to for updates?**

Comment: They are *.sourceforge.net addresses (Just tried with fiddler)

Comment: @AlexK It used to be `*sourceforge.net`, but moved to `nppxml.bruderste.in` in 2016.

Answer (score 4):

**[According to the project's creator](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/issues/75#issuecomment-320361304), Notepad++ Plugin Manager's update URL is hosted on nppxml.bruderste.in**

Hosting was moved from `*.sourceforge.net` to `nppxml.bruderste.in` in October 2016 due to a controversy where [Sourceforge began bundling adware with installers for abandoned projects](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/rise-fall-slashdot-media/).

- **New Plugin Manager URL**: [`https://nppxml.bruderste.in/pm/xml/plugins.zip`](https://nppxml.bruderste.in/pm/xml/plugins.zip)

---

From the [sponsor page for NP++ Plugin Manager](https://bruderste.in/npp/pm/sponsor/)

> Since 2010, Plugin Manager has been hosted on Sourceforge.net. They've
>   been a great host for us, and generously supported the large amount of
>   traffic that the plugin manager generates. To put some numbers on the
>   traffic, whilst the plugin list is only 50KB, and is normally only
>   download when it changes, each change generates around 500GB of
>   traffic, with a steady 200GB of traffic each month.
>
> **In 2015 there was some controversy surrounding SourceForge bundling
>   adware with abandoned projects.** This has since been cleared up, and we
>   applaud SourceForge for taking the right path in this regard. However,
>   this sparked some discussion and thinking around what we could do to
>   **transfer the hosting of the list off SourceForge and onto another
>   provider**, and what benefits and disadvantages that would bring. There
>   are things we aren't able to do easily with the sourceforge hosting
>   system, and relying on the goodwill of a website is not good in the
>   long run for the project. Using a more traditional hosting platform
>   would allow us to address some of the current issues we have around
>   automating the list updates, and serving a dynamic "bleeding edge"
>   list.
>
> **So, I'm very grateful to Nexinto that they are sponsoring the hosting and bandwidth requirements for Notepad++ Plugin Manager**, and hope you can forgive the small logo and link in the plugin which means we are reliably hosted on VMs that we control, and hence can extend what we do, bringing automatic fortnightly releases of new plugins to the plugin manager.

---

<sub>For reference, the old url was [`https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/npppluginmgr/xml/plugins.zip`](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/npppluginmgr/xml/plugins.zip)</sub>

Comment: nppxml.bruderste.in --> {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}

Comment: nppxml.bruderste.in --> 
Error 521
Ray ID: 5ca03c1448f60dae • 2020-08-28 18:53:22 UTC
Web server is down

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure if problem is proxy but plugin list is no displayed, try the next. 
From "Plugin Manager, Settings", select checkbox "Use development plugin list (may contain untested, unvalidated or uninstallable plugins)

At the moment for v7.5 and v7.6:

- Proxy setting are no displayed from Plugins Manager interface
- Plugins server is  http://nppxml.bruderste.in
- Downloaded files by Plugin Manager:

  - http://nppxml.bruderste.in/pm/xml/plugins.zip
  - http://nppxml.bruderste.in/pm/xml/plugins2.md5.txt